# Remove the Nav from SwiftUI after hiding the back button

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to remove the space that is left after hiding the back icon after navigation to the second view?[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)){
                    Text("View Two")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("View Two")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something pretty interesting [here](https://filipmolcik.com/how-to-hide-swiftui-navigationbar/). Apparently when you want to hide the navigation bar you also have to "" the title.

Answer (score 0):

That is the `NavigationBar` you left there in the `SecondView`. You should tell it to ignore safe area to get rid of that entirely:

```
SecondView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

**Note that** the `NavigationBar` will stay there and prevents all touch event from passing to `view`s underneath. So if you have any button on top of the view (like the example image), it will not work. You may consider using `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to completely get rid of it.

Currently there is a bug for this last modifier and you may consider [this workaround](https://filipmolcik.com/how-to-hide-swiftui-navigationbar/) until Apple fixes this.

---

#### Suggestion:

Although this is not an answer to the original question, but I strongly recommend that move `SecondView()` modifiers into the `struct SecondView` it self like:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // This one may be considered by the original use case.
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: It `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` even my nav title and hide it. Here is the thing am solving. I have onboarding process to the app which happens only once when the user downloads the application. The user will be taken through the entire process and then home. The second time they will be directed to the dashboard, the issue is after onboarding it still presents the back button which I manage to hide but the view that hosts the back still remains but after opening the app for the second time it's ok. That's the issue am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fully hide the navigation bar you also need to set the navigation bar title to "" (empty string). Moreover, it is a good practice to set the display mode to inline. Here is a code example:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View Two")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Note that I am also taking @Mojatba Hosseini's suggestion into consideration. It makes the code much simpler and easier to read/find whatever you look for.

Furthermore, I would suggest you creating a View extension to hide the navigation bar wherever you need to with just one line of code. The extension should look like this:

```
extension View {
    func hideNavigationBar() -> some View {
        self
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

and here is an example usage relevant to your case:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View Two")
        }
        .hideNavigationBar()
    }
}
```